# Installed Android 4.0 now cannot run project - missing resources.ap_

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I installed Android 4.0 and updated the Eclipse plugin.
Now I cannot run any of my projects and get an error stating the following:

**Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Projects\Android\HelloAndroid\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist**

This is coming from a very simple "Hello World" app.

Anybody know how to get the resources.ap_ file generating again?

Comment: Creating a new project and trying to run gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same error (also referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714711/android-packaging-problem-resources-ap-does-not-exist/7840604#7840604)) using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) after upgrading to ADT 14 and SDK 14 on all projects including newly created ones. I found a workaround someone posted on the ADT bug tracker, which is basically to switch Eclipse Settings->Android->Build->Build Output from "Verbose" to "Normal". The post is [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20395#c11).

Comment: This is not working for me. I am still getting the same error. Desperately need help.